# Add to cart ajax not working with secure and unsecure url

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, ajax

All Ajax is working perfectly when we are using secure base url = https or http and unsercure base url = https or http.

When we add secure base url = https and unsecure base url = http. Now we have access store using https, Ajax working perfect. But we are using http, ajax not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "ajax not working" a bit: Did you do some debugging so far? What is the response you get in the developer console that is sent back from your AJAX request?

Comment: Ajax add to cart is not a standard functionality of Magento. Can you post the code that does this?

Comment: Actually we are using theme. Theme demo url is http://demo.saharathemes.com/ma_sahara_furniture456/index.php/?___store=en
In this theme have inbuilt functionality to ajax add to cart.

Comment: Its send error "url is 302 moved temporarily"

Comment: @kruti did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

In the source code from this theme you point out I can see an option:

```
<input class="using_ssl" type="hidden" value="0">
```

Maybe you have to search for a setting in this ajax cart module?

Comment: How we can change this input value.